Why does East Asian text have wide spacing on terminal?
It seems all terminal apps under Linux desktop show wide spacing for East Asian text, but not for Western test.

Terminal apps don't seem to support selecting proportional fonts, but even if I select a mono font in Libre Writer, East Asian texts don't show that kind of spacing.

Another example: the same Japanese text file shown in a terminal editor (Micro, left) and in a GUI editor (FeatherPad, right)

Why do terminal apps show such wide spacing?

Do you have a monospace font with support for those characters?

The font I used for Writer is "aur/adobe-source-han-mono-kr-fonts 1.002-7 (+8 0.00) Adobe Source Han Mono - A set of Pan-CJK fonts designed to complement Source Code Pro". I think it contains mono fonts for at least Korean.

you mean "East Asian text" and not Asian

Yes, eosyllabric scripts like Brahmic scripts, and alphabets like Mchedruli (modern Georgian script), the Arabic script (and descendatns, like the Persian alphabet), Mongolian and the many other writing systems of the most population-rich continent tend to have different embedding rules than the logographically descended (Hanzi, the Chines characters, and Kanji, the adaptation of these by the Japanese writing system) languages, and languages that intermingle syllabic with such symbolic glyphs (Japanese with its two syllabic notations and its one symbolic, usually found mixed in words). Hangul

is a bit special in that it's syllabic, and very much royally designed, which might have influenced the inventors and reformers to adapt a bit of a Chinese "shape and feel", whilst making the writing system alphabetic-syllabic to make it easier to learn.

Actually, the Classic Terminal emulators follow the Unicode Standard's East Asian Width (EAW) specification, which classifies characters as full-width or half-width. Asian characters (like Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Thai and some Indian languages) are usually full-width, meaning they occupy the space of two ASCII characters.
On the other hand, modern emulators that are embedded in other applications like VS code, eclipse, and so on do not adhere to this "two characters space" requirement. This is why such difference is noticeable at the first glance.

VSCode displays fonts in two ways.  The editor panes are not a terminal emulator.  The terminal emulator definitely uses fullwidth for East Asian (though its rendering isn't as good as some other terminal emulators).  The tone of this answer is too biased to upvote.
